# Usage of sí vs sí mismo

Tags: uso-de-palabras, pronombres

It seems to me that the words "sí" and "sí mismo" both refer to the subject of a verb (reflexively), but I don't know when to use one or the other.

Me parece que las palabras "sí" y "sí mismo" se refieren al sujeto del verbo, pero no sé cuál sería la distinción entre ellas.

Comment: The pun "Lo hizo para sí sismo" is rather usual in some "dialects"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según la definición de [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/s%C3%AD):

> ## *Sí*
>
> Forma tónica del **pronombre personal reflexivo** de tercera persona, que
> en la oración desempeña la función de complemento con preposición.
>   ♦ Al unirse con la preposición *con*, forma la voz
> *consigo*.

En esta [página web (en inglés)](http://www.elearnspanishlanguage.com/grammar/pronouns/reflexiveprepositionalpronouns.html) puedes encontrar información y ejemplos sobre los pronombres personales reflexivos en español.

En esa página se dice que:

> Todos los pronombres personales reflexivos pueden ir seguidos del adjetivo ***mismo*** (o misma/mismos/mismas, dependiendo del género y el número del sujeto) con el fin de **enfatizar el aspecto reflexivo**.

Por lo tanto, en principio **podrías usar indistintamente `sí` o `sí mismo`**. La única diferencia es que al añadir el adjetivo `mismo` estás recalcando un poco más la reflexividad de la acción.

---

Sin embargo -y esto ya es un poco una opinión personal- pienso que la mayoría de las frases suenan mejor con la forma `sí mismo`. Por ejemplo:

> Hizo todo el trabajo ***por sí misma***.
> Estaba hablando ***consigo mismo*** en su habitación.
> A partir de ahora tendrá que cuidar ***de sí mismo***.
> Está hablando ***de sí misma*** constantemente.

En mi opinión, todas estas frases sonarían peor si omitiésemos el adjetivo `mismo`. Por lo tanto, mi consejo personal es que uses siempre la forma `sí mismo`, ya que es la que suena mejor en la gran mayoría de situaciones. Sin embargo esto no es para nada una regla establecida, sino una simple opinión personal...

Answer (score 4):

Indeed *sí* is the third person (singular and plural) reflexive pronoun, when used after a preposition.

> Yo lo hice para mí (mismo). *I did it for myself.*
>
> Tú lo hiciste para ti (mismo). *You did it for yourself.*
>
> El lo hizo para sí (mismo). *He did it for himself.*
>
> Ella lo hizo para sí (misma). *Shi did it for herself.*
>
> Nosotros lo hicimos para nosotros (mismos). *We did it for ourselves.*
>
> Vosotros lo hicisteis para vosotros (mismos). *You did it for yourselves.*
>
> Ellos lo hicieron para sí (mismos). *They did it for themselves.*

The word *mismo* (*self*) is used either for emphasis (usually to make an emphasis that the pronoun is reflexive) or to avoid confusion, particularly in the plural.

> Somos conscientes de nosotros.

might either mean *“We are conscious of each other ”* or *“we are conscious of ourselves”*, adding *mismos* removes the ambiguity.  Most times, however, you can drop *mismo(s)*, so *sí* and *sí mismo* are usually interchangeable when no emphasis is intended.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not the subject.  It's the object.

From the way you asked the question, I have a feeling you were *thinking* **object** but you maybe misspoke.

Let's look at some examples:

1. No lo haga usted por mí, hágalo por sí mismo.
2. Señora, ¿se acuerda usted de algo de lo que pasó antes de volver en sí?
3. Antes de querer al otro, tiene usted que aprender a quererse a sí mismo.

Notes:

1. Here, *sí mismo* is the object of a preposition.
2. Here, *volver en sí* is a special expression that means *to come around after having lost consciousness*.
3. Here, *sí mismo* is the object of the verb *querer*.